# I want to blur my parent grid with black shade at the time of popup in uwp. Is there any way to implement this in uwp

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am creating a dextop application using uwp in xaml. i want to make the parent screen to blur black at time of popup. Is there any way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to blur my parent grid with black shade at the time of popup in uwp. Is there any way to implement this in uwp

You could use [`Loading`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/loading) control to archive this feature.

```
<controls:Loading x:Name="LoadingControl" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
      <controls:Loading.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="BurlyWood" Opacity="0.6" />
      </controls:Loading.Background>
      <ContentControl x:Name="LoadingContentControl" />
</controls:Loading>
```

If you do want to make the parent screen to blur black, please replace `Background` with `AcrylicBrush`

```
<Page.Resources>
    <AcrylicBrush x:Key="CustomAcrylicBrush" BackgroundSource="Backdrop"
        TintOpacity="0.2" TintColor="#FF000000" FallbackColor="#FF008000" />
</Page.Resources>


<controls:Loading x:Name="LoadingControl" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="{StaticResource CustomAcrylicBrush}">
            <TextBlock Text="Isloading" Foreground="Black"/>
</controls:Loading>
```

Comment: its working but i have another issue with this. i have a parent grid and on the delete button event i am showing the popup above the parent grid. Using acrylic the parent is getting blur but not taking black color. It is showing a white shade, i think that is because of the background of content dialogue if the popup. Even tintOpacity is also not working.